# Anime in which the main character controls a drone that looks like a flying eyeball

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots

Anime about robotics. (Not about giant robots or mechas. Also, it can only hardly be called sci-fi.)

In the first scene of the first episode, the main character (MC) is shown to be controlling a drone (that looks like a flying eyeball) which he apparently made, and he also meets a girl in the same scene.

Afterwards, in the first or maybe the second episode, the MC along with a few others have a team deathmatch with miniature tanks.

I dropped after episode 1 or 2, so I don't remember much else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[RoboMasters: The Animated Series](https://myanimelist.net/anime/34903/RoboMasters_the_Animated_Series)*.

> The series depicts college students as they prepare and participate in a RoboMasters tournament.
>
> [image]

### Opening Theme (cued to eyeball drone)

### Closing Theme